# Accessing the root html tag for a Controller in ember

Tags: ember.js

The following searches the entire DOM tree, not what I want.

```
$('input.js-search')
```

In Backbone I can do this.

```
this.$('input.js-search')
```

This tells jquery to search based on the root html element of the current Backbone View.  So if there were 10 instances of this view on the screen at the same time, it would only return a single one each time not 10 (ie, the one belonging to the view).

How can I do something like this in **Ember** from a **Controller**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, Views are generally associated with each controller.  So if you are trying to work on your `FooController`, create a `FooView` and do the work there.  It's important to note that your element won't be in the page until `didInsertElement` has been called.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  gitterDone: function(){
    this.$('button').addClass('coolButton');
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lecojeca/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not without unsafely accessing a lot private/protected member variables. And even if you wanted to do that, it still wouldn't solve your problem.

> So if there were 10 instances of this view on the screen at the same time, it would only return a single one each time not 10 (ie, the one belonging to the view).

Controllers can have more than one view, so even if there was something equivalent to `this.$()`, it wouldn't solve your problem.

Only views can access their DOM contents directly, so you would have to do whatever logic you need in your view (which has access to its controller). Views have a `$` property, so you can do exactly as you described and walk their DOM tree with `this.$(selector)`.